# running the repository locally in jekyll

Tags: ruby, jekyll, hosting, bundler

I had download the zip file of (https://github.com/hotosm/hotosm-website.git)
I want to run website locally in Ubuntu but each item its giving error:

```
Deprecation: The 'plugins' configurationoption has been renamed to 'plugins_dir'. Please update your config file accordingly.
       Deprecation: You appear to have pagination turned on, but you haven't included the `jekyll-paginate` gem. Ensure you have `gems: [jekyll-paginate]` in your configuration file.
Jekyll initialised repository-Jekyll new <file name> -file is running fine at  (HTTP://127.0.0.1:4000/) ,but its not working in repository.
this sites uses bundle,ruby,and Jekyll.
```

Answer (score 0):

Change line https://github.com/hotosm/hotosm-website/blob/c391b3b96ab3d514959f1800793635aeafcfcb85/_config.yml#L245 to **plugins_dir**. That is what the warning is.